# Finding ordered bases for a vector space $\mathbb C^n$

Tags: linear-algebra

How do you find two ordered bases, B and B' for the vector space $\mathbb C^n$ (Complex numbers over field $\mathbb R$) where one of the bases should not contain a $\mathbb R$-scalar multiple of a vector in the other basis?
And then find an invertible matrix P such that for any v in $\mathbb C^n$, [v]B = P[v]B'

Comment: Can you give us some more context here?  Do you have a particular basis in mind?  What are you trying to accomplish by constructing this new basis?

Comment: Sure. I edited the question to add more context.